# Trying to display both mean and median with gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

What is the correct syntax to display both median and mean of a continuous variable using tbl_continuous? Also, is it possible to display on 2 lines as you can do with tbl_summary and the continuous2 argument?

Code below is just displaying medians (see image).

```
comparison.data %>%
  select(imaging, los.minutes, acuity) %>%
  tbl_continuous(
    by = imaging,
    variable = los.minutes,
    statistic = 
     los.minutes ~ c("{mean} ({sd})", 
                     "{median} ({sd})")
  ) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Imaging status**")
```

[Just displaying medians](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIuUv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.1'

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  tbl_continuous(
    variable = age, 
    by = trt,
    include = grade,
    statistic = ~"{mean}  \n{median}"
  ) %>% 
  as_gt() %>% 
  gt::fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hmmm...median and mean are showing up on the same line with this---    statistic = ~"{median} \n{mean}"

Comment: you need two spaces in from of the \n FYI